# How can I remove the non-alphanumeric (English) characters in a series containing strings while retaining spaces?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Currently, I have:

```
[re.sub(r'\W', '', i) for i in training_data.loc[:, 'Text']]
```

However with this the Hindi characters remain and all the spaces are removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Negation might help

```
import re
import string    

re.sub(f'[^{string.printable}]', '', 'asdf #$שדגכ')
```